# store multiple query results at a time (mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to store the results of query

SELECT column_name from table_name limit 2

into variables, says, @w1 , @w2

What are the correct syntax?

I tried 
"Set @w1, @w2 = (SELECT column_name from table_name limit ); "

and similar ones but it hasn't work.

Thank.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: _**@OP**_: You may want to use [SELECT ... INTO Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT @a := (SELECT column_name FROM table_name ORDER BY value LIMIT 1) as a) a,
(SELECT @b := (SELECT column_name FROM table_name ORDER BY value LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1) as b) b
```

Please note that `limit` won't make much sense if you do not use `ORDER BY`.